# OS X mc (Midnight Commander) copy to clipboard

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, mc

Recently I got a Macbook Pro. I can't manage to copy any sing in mceditor to clipboard and paste. No solutions seems to work.

Command+V - does paste a text from the buffer, but Command+C does nothing, I can't copy to buffer.

Comment: Have you seen [the list of commands](https://gist.github.com/sgergely/3793166)? Command+C to copy and Command+V to paste, no? Or using *Edit* menu (Fn+F9).

Comment: None of the shortcuts you've mentioned work for me in mcedit.

Comment: Consider giving far2l a try, it has mc-like interface and supports clipboard well. https://github.com/elfmz/far2l

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As seen in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/262668/14586), you can use the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut to disable "Mouse Reporting" in your Terminal window.

Or you can leave "Mouse Reporting" on to be able to use your mouse in MC, but press <kbd>Fn</kbd> to disable it just while selecting text to copy.

More details in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/985865/53547).

Comment: For iTerm2: `Preferences -> Profile -> Terminal -> Mouse Reporting -> uncheck`

Comment: In `iTerm2` hold `Option ⌥` while selecting. `Copy` from the context menu also works, but will copy only a single word.

Answer (score 5):

Run mc with -d switch (mc -d). It will disable mouse features in mc and now you can copy with LMB+select and paste with Cmd+RMB

Answer (score 1):

1) Select text in File1 by F3(select block)
2) Run Menu (F9 edit/[copy to buff file] aka C-Ins)
3) Open File2
4) Run Menu (F9 edit/[paste from buff file] aka S-Ins)

Comment: I need a keyboard shortcut.